# Does anything in 2 Samuel 13:20-22 Hebrew text hint that King David reaction as Only being angry be because of feelings of hypocrisy?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy

It might be circuitous/tortuous reasoning but here goes:

1. David has adulterous sinful sexual relations with Bathsheba
2. Prophet Nathan confronts David about his sin
3. David feels remorseful, and therefore repents
4. Prophet Nathan does say God forgives David but there are still going to be consequences due to said sexual sin
5. David's eldest son, Amnon, rapes his half-sister, Tamar
6. David hears about the aforementioned rape, but can Only be angry because

   a) he feels hypocritical due to his own adulterous sinful sexual affair with Bathsheba

   b) also, David recollects that Prophet Nathan did still say that negative consequences would        happen due to David's aforementioned sin

**Note:2 Samuel 13:20-22 gives an account of David's anger immediately after the story about Amnon raping Tamar. Let me explain, 2 Samuel 13:20-22 verse was mentioned immediately just after the story of Amnon raping Tamar, and then Tamar being in shame. Furthermore, only later on when we read 2 Samuel 13:23-38 gives account of Absalom's taking revenge by killing Amnon. Finally, as we continue to read past 2 Samuel 15 , we learn that Absalom leads a rebellion or coup d'etat against King David. **

Does anything in 2 Samuel 13:20-22 Hebrew text hint that King David reaction as Only being angry is because of David's own hypocrisy due to adultery?

**Interesting Side Note: I suppose a better term to use to describe David's angry reaction would be the term "galling" because David might have felt caught in his own "web of hypocrisy"**

> 2 Samuel 13:20-22
>
> 20 Then Absalom her brother said to her, “Has Amnon
> your brother been with you? But now keep silent, my sister,  he is
> your brother; do not take this matter to heart.” So Tamar remained and
> was desolate in her brother  Absalom’s house. **21 Now when King David
> heard of all these matters, he was very angry.** 22 But Absalom did
> not  speak to Amnon either good or bad; for Absalom hated Amnon
> because he had violated his sister Tamar.
>
> 13:21 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex וְהַמֶּ֣לֶךְ דָּוִ֔ד
> שָׁמַ֕ע אֵ֥ת כָּל־הַדְּבָרִ֖ים הָאֵ֑לֶּה וַיִּ֥חַר לֹ֖ו מְאֹֽד׃
>
> שמואל ב 13:21 Hebrew OT: WLC (Consonants Only) והמלך דוד שמע את
> כל־הדברים האלה ויחר לו מאד׃
>
> שמואל ב 13:21 Paleo-Hebrew OT: WLC (Font Required) והמלך דוד שמע את
> כל־הדברים האלה ויחר לו מאד׃
>
> שמואל ב 13:21 Hebrew Bible והמלך דוד שמע את כל הדברים האלה ויחר לו
> מאד׃

Comment: You first need to prove whether David's anger was against Amnon for his behaviour to Tamar or whether David's anger was against Absalom for acting as if he had the royal and paternal authority to intervene in the matter. Was this the beginning of Absalom's rebellion ? Was David angry at both ?

Comment: 2 Samuel 13:20-22 is definitely about David's anger in response to Amnon raping Tamar.  Let me explain, the 2 Samuel 13:20-22 verse was mentioned immediately just after the story of Amnon raping Tamar, and then Tamar being in shame.  Furthermore, only later on when we read 2 Samuel 13:23-38 gives  account of Absalom's taking revenge by killing Amnon. Finally, as we continue to read past 2 Samuel 15 , we learn that Absalom leads a rebellion or coup d'etat against King David.